# How to retrieve DATETIME format from Sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite, java.util.date

I have stored date (java.util.date object) in a DATETIME field of a Sqlite table. Now, how to retrieve this date which would be of the same format as java.util.date. Actually I want to compare the time difference (in milliseconds) between current date and the store date.

Comment: http://sberka.blogspot.com/2009/07/date-time-sqlite-and-android.html check this..

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Retrieve as Cursor.getString() and pass that value to SimpleDateFormat to make the date object. There is no straight method for getting the date object.

Comment: How to passed Fri Oct 23 00:00:00 EDT 2015 ? :(

Answer (score 14):

Here's code that I used to perform what @Gopinath suggested:

```
Calendar t = new GregorianCalendar();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY",Locale.getDefault());
java.util.Date dt = sdf.parse(c.getString(4)); //replace 4 with the column index
t.setTime(dt);
```

Answer (score 2):

In java `SimpleDateFormat`

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

if you want millisecons `anyDAteObject.getTime();`

Comment: The link is dead. Here is from Android documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html