# Getting DATETIME value from Cursor?

Tags: android

I have a `ContentProvider` where the underlying SQLite table has a `DATETIME` field. However, I am not sure how to access the `DATETIME` values from the cursor returned by the provider since there doesnt seem to be a method to get a Date object from the cursor. Should I be treating it as a string and parse it to a Date object somehow?

Comment: Have you had a look at this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255830/fetching-date-from-sqlite-database-in-android or this :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999947/how-to-retrieve-datetime-format-from-sqlite-database

Comment: Yes, get the value as a string, parse it into DateTime programatically. What you are looking for is already answered here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14255830/fetching-date-from-sqlite-database-in-android